# How to set GitHub Actions ENV with python shell

Tags: environment-variables, github-actions

Okay, here is a common example how to set ENVs if we have a bash shell:

```yaml
...

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set environment variable
        shell: bash
        run: echo "ENV_NAME=ENV_VALUE" >> "${GITHUB_ENV}"

      - name: Get environment variable
        shell: bash
        run: echo "A value of ENV_NAME is ${{ env.ENV_NAME }}"
```

But what if our shell is a python?:

```yaml
...

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set environment variable with python
        shell: python
        # How to set ENV with python?
        run: ???
```

How to set ENV with python?

Comment: What happens in that shell script line is that a piece of text is appended to the filename stored in the GITHUB_ENV variable. Using the standard Python `file.WriteLines` function should work just fine.

Comment: @jessehouwing stupid me... it was obvious. Working like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to `@jessehouwing` comment: `GITHUB_ENV` is just a file name. And we able to insert variable by editing this file:

```yaml
...

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set environment variable with python
        shell: python
        run: |
          from os import environ as env

          file_path = env.get('GITHUB_ENV', None)
          if file_path is None:
            raise OSError('Environment file not found')

          with open(file_path, 'a') as gh_envs:
            gh_envs.write('ENV_NAME=ENV_VALUE\n')
```

＊ `GITHUB_ENV` is not a part of [`env`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#env-context) context, so `open('${{ env.GITHUB_ENV }}', 'a')` can not be used

Comment: That does not fully work as is read by python as "***" if you want a secret. The problem is that github obfuscates the secret. I am still trying to figure out a solution.

Comment: @user18140022 All secrets already accessible via `secrets.SECRET_NAME` context. Also it may be set inside `env:` key like `ENV_NAME: ${{secrets.SECRET_NAME}`. I can't imagine why you need to assign secret environment variable via python

Comment: I need different envs for dev, qa, prod. In each environment there are credentials for different databases. That's why I need to assign secret environment variables. I could obvs set them all as repo secret but not ideal